# Google Sankey chart - adjust height automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization, sankey-diagram

Is there a way to make Google Sankey Chart to adjust it's height automatically?

I have a problem with height when I want to draw a lot of rows. Please check fiddle example, because there is a lot of rows, they cannot be all displayed, and the console is showing massive amount of errors like:

```
Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute height="-20.76923076923077"
```

If i reduce number of rows, everything is fine. I want it to set height automatically depending of number of rows.

Here is the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/p0hayw9x/19/

Anyone came across this before?

**UPDATE:**

I have found a workaround, basically multiplying number of rows times fixed value and setting this dynamically as height. Something like:

```
    var rowsQty = data.getNumberOfRows();
    var autoHeight = rowsQty*15;
```

But I don't feel that this is reliable solution.

Comment: adjusting the height according to # of rows seems fine, however you might want to set a min or max on that...

Comment: There is another issue with this workaround, as each row can have different height depending on given weight..